# SQLITE small in file size?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-layout

Okay I am creating an app thats a scrabble cheat basically...  I have noticed that all the other apps can work without the internet meaning they must store their data(words) in an sql database or sorts.  I was planning on doing the same thing.  I exported my mysql database which is on my mac and it was 13.2 mb which i believe is quite alot.  Anyhow when I looked at the other apps on the market that do the same thing as mine they all had sizes in the kb's.  Is there a big difference between mysql sizes compared to sqlite.  And I don't know if I am viewing app sizes right.  Here is how i do it.  Setting> Application> Manage Application and under each package it says the size.  Is that where I should look for the size of the app.  How can I scale my db into my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of factors that could be affecting the size of the apps you're seeing in the market vs. your mysql dump.

1) The size of their databases / schemas and the number of words they include.  Every time you add a column of data to your database, you're effectively increasing the size of the database geometrically (that is, if you add one row in a 2x3 database, you're actually adding 3 more cells (1col x 3 rows).  If you have 10,000 words in your dictionary, you can see how that would increase the size of your database very quickly.  Step 1: Remove all unnecessary columns from the database

2) The files on the Android market are .apk files, which are essentially very compressed archive files.  Since SQLite databases are basically just fancy text files, the compression algorithms used to create the package are very good at compressing this data.  Once you create your .apk, you'll see the size of the application drop dramatically (our game Zomblings went from 60MB uncompressed to a 10M .apk file).  Step 2: generate the apk and see what files size you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to trade time for space, you could store the word list as a compressed text file with your app. Then, on first launch, create a new database and copy the word list in.

If you did this on a background thread as soon as the app launched, you could probably be done before the user did their first word search (though of course you should have some mechanism to signal the main thread you are done, and ask the user to please wait if you are not).